# Change result based on selection dropdown Option

Tags: jquery, css

I created a small form that calculates the amount of people with the amount they would like to spend, based off a per person instance or the group as a whole:

https://jsfiddle.net/g7zz6/661/

```
Men: <input type="text" class="number men-value" value="1"><br>
Women: <input type="text" class="number women-value" value="1"><br>
Total Spend: <input type="text" class="number amount-value" placeholder="Amount" name="amount">
<select>
<option>per person</option>
<option>group total</option>
</select>

<div class="group-total-spend">
$<span class="total-amount-group"></span> Group Total<br>
$<span class="total-amount-per-person"></span> Per Person
</div>
```

Some things I am having trouble with that I need to add:

When the option "per person" is selected, I need only "Group Total" to be visible" and when "group total" is selected, I need only "Per Person" to be visible.

Another issue is that I don't want the calculation to be visible until ALL 3 fields are filled out. My way around it now is to have defaulted values of 1 for the Men and Women fields - because if they both have a value of 0, I get a value of "NaN". Would be nice to stop from allowing 0 to be in both Men and Women fields at the same. Right now what I have makes the container ".group-total-spend" show as soon as any value is inputted. This would become obsolete if I can figure out a way to combine all 3 to make it visible.

```
$('input[name=amount]').keyup(function(){
if($(this).val().length)
$('.group-total-spend').show();
    else
    $('.group-total-spend').hide();
});
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can lend a hand. I know this probably easy stuff, but I am just getting into jQuery and learning as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this JSFiddle i updated the code: https://jsfiddle.net/g7zz6/664/ hope it helps :)

HTML:

```
Men <input type="text" class="number men-value" value="1"><br>
Women <input type="text" class="number women-value" value="1"><br>
Total Spend <input type="text" class="number amount-value" placeholder="Amount" name="amount">
<select id="option">
<option value="perPerson">per person</option>
<option value="groupTotal">group total</option>
</select>

<div class="group-total-spend">
    <p id="groupTotal">$<span class="total-amount-group"></span> Group Total</p>
    <p id="perPerson">$<span class="total-amount-per-person"></span> Per Person</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
/* Start Group Spend */

/* Allow Numbers Only */
jQuery('.number').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});

/* Calculate Total */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.number").keyup(function(){
        calcTotal();                                                                  
    });

    $("select#option").change(function() {
        calcTotal();
    });
});

function calcTotal() {

    $('p#perPerson').hide();
    $('p#groupTotal').hide();

    var val1 = parseInt($(".men-value").val(), 10);
    var val2 = parseInt($(".women-value").val(), 10);        
    var val3 = parseInt($(".amount-value").val(), 10);        

    if (isNaN(val1) || isNaN(val2) || isNaN(val3)) {              
        return false;
    }

    var group = val1+val2         
    var tresult = group * val3
    var ppresult = tresult / group                             
    var option = $("select#option").val();

    switch(option) {
        case "perPerson":
            $('span.total-amount-per-person').text(ppresult);
            $("p#perPerson").show();
            break;
        case "groupTotal":
            $('span.total-amount-group').text(tresult);
            $("p#groupTotal").show();                  
            break;
    }
}
/* End Group Spend */
```

CSS:

```
.group-total-spend p {display:none;margin-top:10px;border-top:1px solid #000;padding-top:10px;width:50%;}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help...this seems to work almost perfect, but I need the results to be the opposite! When "Per Person" is selected from the drop down, the result should show how much as a Group Total and vice versa. Please, can you also check on my calculations, thanks!

Comment: Yup, I got it, thank you! :)

Surprised no one caught my mathematical error, though. The per person result or "ppresult" should be "val3 / group" not "tresult / group" - but I got it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Check the updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/g7zz6/669/.

HTML

```
Men
<input type="text" class="number men-value" value="1">
<br>Women
<input type="text" class="number women-value" value="1">
<br>Total Spend
<input type="text" class="number amount-value" placeholder="Amount" name="amount">
<select id="categoryselect">
    <option>per person</option>
    <option>group total</option>
</select>
<div class="group-total-spend">
    <span class="total-amount-group">
        $<label></label> Group Total</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="total-amount-per-person">
        $<label></label> Per Person</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
      /* Allow Numbers Only */
jQuery('.number').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
});

/* Show/Hide Total */
$('input[name=amount]').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) $('.group-total-spend').show();
    else $('.group-total-spend').hide();
});

/* Calculate Total */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.number").keyup(function () {
        calculate();
    });
});
/* End Group Spend */

function calculate() {
    var val1 = parseInt($(".men-value").val(), 10);
    var val2 = parseInt($(".women-value").val(), 10);
    var group = val1 + val2;
    var val3 = parseInt($(".amount-value").val(), 10);
    var selectedIndex = $("#categoryselect").prop('selectedIndex');
    var tresult = group * val3;
    var ppresult = tresult / group;
    if (selectedIndex === 1) {
        tresult = val3;
        ppresult = val3 / group;
    }


    $('.total-amount-group').find('label').text(tresult);
    $('.total-amount-per-person').find('label').text(ppresult);
    if ($(".men-value").val().length > 0 && $(".women-value").val().length > 0) {
        if (selectedIndex === 0) {
            $('.total-amount-group').show();
            $('.total-amount-per-person').hide();
        } else {
            $('.total-amount-group').hide();
            $('.total-amount-per-person').show();
        }
    } else {
        $('.total-amount-group').hide();
        $('.total-amount-per-person').hide();
    }
}

$("#categoryselect").change(function () {
    calculate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of the fields before showing the result.

```
if(($(".men-value").val() != "") && ($(".women-value").val() != "") && ($(".amount-value").val() !="")){
  // calculation here
}
```

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7zz6/662/).

Answer (score 0):

To make the divs visible only when all three inputs are full I'd use a simple counter

```
var filled=0;
$('input').each(function(){
   if($(this).val()!='')
      filled++;
});
if(filled==3){
   $('.group-total-spend').show();
   $('.total-amount-group').text(tresult);
   $('.total-amount-per-person').text(ppresult);
}else{
   $('.group-total-spend').hide();            
}
```

Then the select just have a toggle

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='per person'){
        $('#group').hide();
        $('#person').show();
    }else{
        $('#group').show();
        $('#person').hide();
    }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrh6g9h0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/g7zz6/667/)

This should do it all -- *please note there were minute changes to your markup*:

```
$(function() {
    $('input.number,select').on('keypress change', function(e) {
        if( $(this).is('.number') && e.which && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) ) {
            console.log( e.which );
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        var filled = $('input.number').filter(function() {
            return this.value.trim().length > 0;
        });
        $('.group-total-spend')[filled.length === 3 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
        if( filled.length === 3 ) {
            var val1 = parseInt($(".men-value").val(), 10);
            var val2 = parseInt($(".women-value").val(), 10);
            var group = val1+val2
            var val3 = parseInt($(".amount-value").val(), 10);
            var tresult = group * val3
            var ppresult = tresult / group
            $('.total-amount-group').text(tresult);
            $('.total-amount-per-person').text(ppresult);

            var sel = $('select').val();console.log( sel );
            $('span.total')[ sel == 'per person' ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
            $('span.person')[ sel == 'group total' ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
        }
    });
});
```